# System.DllNotFoundException even though *.so file exists in the respective lib folder

Tags: android, android-ndk, xamarin.android

I'm currently developing an Android app that utilizes an existing native library written in C.

I managed to run the app on a Motorola Moto G2 (Android 6.0, armeabi-v7a), but on a Galaxy S2 (Android 4.1.2, also armeabi-v7a) I always get a `DllNotFoundException`.

When I run `adb shell ls -l /data/data/com.my.app/lib` I can see that the `libmyutils.so` is extracted from the respective ABI lib folder.

In the debug log is can see a lot of lines like this:

```
01-25 15:44:55.397 D/Mono    (27537): DllImport error loading library './libmyutils': 'Cannot load library: load_library[1094]: Library '/data/data/com.my.app/lib/./libmyutils' not found'.
01-25 15:44:55.397 D/Mono    (27537): DllImport error loading library './libmyutils.so': 'Cannot load library: find_library[1202]:   138 'libmyutils.so' failed to load previously'.
01-25 15:44:55.397 D/Mono    (27537): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libmyutils': 'Cannot load library: load_library[1094]: Library '/data/data/com.my.app/lib//system/lib/libmyutils' not found'.
01-25 15:44:55.397 D/Mono    (27537): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libmyutils.so': 'Cannot load library: find_library[1202]:   138 'libmyutils.so' failed to load previously'.
01-25 15:44:55.397 D/Mono    (27537): DllImport error loading library 'libmyutils': 'Cannot load library: load_library[1094]: Library '/data/data/com.my.app/lib/libmyutils' not found'.
01-25 15:44:55.397 D/Mono    (27537): DllImport error loading library 'libmyutils.so': 'Cannot load library: find_library[1202]:   138 'libmyutils.so' failed to load previously'.
01-25 15:44:55.397 D/Mono    (27537): DllImport error loading library 'myutils': 'Cannot load library: load_library[1094]: Library '/data/data/com.my.app/lib/myutils' not found'.
01-25 15:44:55.397 D/Mono    (27537): DllImport error loading library './libmyutils': 'Cannot load library: load_library[1094]: Library '/data/data/com.my.app/lib/./libmyutils' not found'.
01-25 15:44:55.397 D/Mono    (27537): DllImport error loading library './libmyutils.so': 'Cannot load library: find_library[1202]:   138 'libmyutils.so' failed to load previously'.
01-25 15:44:55.397 D/Mono    (27537): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libmyutils': 'Cannot load library: load_library[1094]: Library '/data/data/com.my.app/lib//system/lib/libmyutils' not found'.
01-25 15:44:55.397 D/Mono    (27537): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libmyutils.so': 'Cannot load library: find_library[1202]:   138 'libmyutils.so' failed to load previously'.
01-25 15:44:55.397 D/Mono    (27537): DllImport error loading library 'libmyutils': 'Cannot load library: load_library[1094]: Library '/data/data/com.my.app/lib/libmyutils' not found'.
01-25 15:44:55.397 D/Mono    (27537): DllImport error loading library 'libmyutils.so': 'Cannot load library: find_library[1202]:   138 'libmyutils.so' failed to load previously'.
01-25 15:44:55.397 D/Mono    (27537): DllImport error loading library 'libmyutils': 'Cannot load library: load_library[1094]: Library '/data/data/com.my.app/lib/libmyutils' not found'.
01-25 15:44:55.397 W/Mono    (27537): DllImport unable to load library 'Cannot load library: load_library[1094]: Library '/data/data/com.my.app/lib/libmyutils' not found'.
```

Is this a compiler/architecture issue?

I'm looking forward to your help!

Best,
Marco

**UPDATE: Solution**

Finally it works! On the Galaxy S2 Android 4.1.2 I tried to call a native function by using the `DllImport` attribute and specified the library as `myutils`. After I had changed `myutils` to `libmyutils.so` the App was able to find the library. Unfortunately, it couldn't find a dependency library `libdep1.so`. What I did was to load the libraries in the correct order at startup using `Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("dep1")` and then `Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("myutils")`. This works even without the *lib* and *.so* pre-/suffix using only the library name. I could also switch back to from `libmyutils.so` to `myutils` in the `DllImport` attribute library name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old versions of Android had a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34416) in the linker where you had to load your native libraries in a specific order or they wouldn't load properly.

The best way to solve this is to use [ReLinker](https://github.com/KeepSafe/ReLinker). If you aren't using Java, the NDK ships a tool called `ndk-depends` that will tell you the correct load order for your shared libraries.

Note that you'll probably need to explicitly use `Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary` rather than `DllImport`.

Comment: nice thanks! I've just found out that on the Galaxy S2 I have to load *libmyutils.so* instead of *myutils*, now it's able to find the lib (unfortunately it can't find a dependet library now), but it's kind of intressting

Comment: thanks for the ReLinker hint, but I'm using Xamarin (C#)

Comment: Updated my answer to include a non-Java solution.

Comment: thanks for your effort, I actually managed it by loading the libs in the correct load order. But what did the trick was calling `Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary('deplib1')` and then `Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary('myutils)` when the App starts up. Before I tried this I only used the `DllImport` attribute (which did not work). Maybe you could add this hint to your answer then I'll accept it